# How to save several similar models in the hasMany relationship?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

[jsbin example](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/tetafijeci/3/edit?html,js,output)

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">
    model.cards.length: {{model.cards.length}}
    <br>
    <button {{action 'addCardToDeck' card}}>Add card</button>
</script>

App = Ember.Application.create();

App.Card = DS.Model.extend({});

App.Deck = DS.Model.extend({
    cards: DS.hasMany('card', {async: true})
});

App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return this.store.createRecord('deck');
  }
});

App.IndexController = Ember.Controller.extend({
  onInit: function() {
    var card = this.store.createRecord('card');

    this.set('card', card);
  }.on('init'),

  actions: {
    addCardToDeck: function (card) {
     this.get('model.cards').pushObject(card);
    }
  }
});
```

Ember-data does not store models with the same id in a hasMany relation.

How to organize the work hasMany so that can save several similar models?

Comment: Welcome to SO:SE. Please add your current code, the problem you have encountered, and answers will try to fix it. See [ask].

Comment: Add example code to question.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are seeing this issue is not because your model records have the same id but rather because you are trying to push the exact same `card` record into your store each time `addCardToDeck` is called.  To get around this you could reset card to be a newly created object each time `addCardToDeck` is called, although I'm not sure that this is the best way to accomplish what you are after because you'll end up with a lot of empty records in your store.

```
addCardToDeck: function (card) {
  this.get('model.cards').pushObject(card);

  card = this.store.createRecord('card');    
  this.set('card', card);
}
```

Comment: This is not the solution. Empty objects will not work, will not work with server part.

Comment: Correct, you'll need to actually do something with the records in order for them to be unique and save them to your backend.  This just demonstrates why you are getting the problem you are seeing.

Comment: I need models were not unique.

Deck should look something like this:

    {
        deck: {
            id: '1',
            card_ids: [1,1,2,2,3,4,5]
        }
    }